# the name Application does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have an existing winform app which didn't use Program.cs. I wanted to add Program.cs with the usual code

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

but I have the error message

Application doesn't exist in the current context.

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to have a `using` directive for `System.Windows.Forms` in the beginning of the file:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Either that, or modify the `Main` method to use the full type names:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Form1());
```

...though I would recommend the first solution.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you added reference to `System.Windows.Forms` assembly and added reference to `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The [Application class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.aspx) lives in the System.Windows.Forms namespace.  You need to add a reference at the top of that file or explicitly quality the path.

Answer (score 1):

Does the Program.cs file contain `using System.Windows.Forms;`? The `Application`  class is in that namespace.

Answer (score 1):

If you using VS, Use Alt+Shift+F10 it will help you, or install [resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)